# How do I execute functions in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm completely new to actionscript (as3, not as2) and am having some problems with some simple functions and variables. Everything is in one .fla using the actions panel.

How do I get functions to execute? Nothing of my shape changes and there is no output.

*I am aware the first change won't be noticeable, I'll add a timer later on.

Here is the code*:

```
var starBlackWidth = 500;
var starBlackScaleX = 0.5;

function starStretch(){
      starBlack.length = starBlackWidth;
      trace("Stretched the star.");
}
function starReadjust() {
      starBlack.scaleX = starBlackScaleX;
      trace("Attempted at readjusting without using the width directly.");
}
```

Comment: You've defined two functions but there's no code here that actually calls them.

Comment: you need a line at the bottom that calls the functions: `starStretch();` or `starReadjust();`

Answer (score 0):

As some of the commenters pointed out, yes you need to call the functions you created by adding these two lines of code.

```
starStretch();
starReadjust();
```

To expand upon what they said, yes these may be fundamental concepts of programming but if you're new to object oriented programming in as3 and even oop in general this link is extremely helpful at getting you going in as3, its 3 parts and it covers it pretty well!
 http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/08/25/tutorial-understanding-classes-in-as3-part-1/